# "You have mail" welcome message with no mail

Tags: linux, debian

When I login to one of my stations I get this output saying I have mail. But then running the mail commands Says I don't have any email.

What can I do to repair this problem?

```
Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
You have mail.
Last login: Thu Nov 17 01:38:35 2016 from ***.***.***.***
psms1@psms:~$ mail
No mail for psms1
psms1@psms:~$
```

Comment: `rm /var/spool/mail/psms1` ; logout and login to test.

Comment: Run that command and its looking good now. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mailbox is probably corrupted or some email client left there a residual byte/character. Another email client can even say it is empty.

As it is empty, the easier approach it to delete it with the command:

```
rm /var/spool/mail/psms1
```

As such, it will be recreated the next time you receive a message, and the `mail` command will be happy with it.

Answer (score 1):

This is reported when the atime on your mail spool file(s) is the same as the mtime (i.e. the last access modified the file). It might be easier to think about the case where the access time is after the modification time - this implies you read your mail and the message is suppressed.

If you don't have new mail then something else most be changing the mtime on your spool file.

Answer (score 0):

I tried Ribeiro's solution on a shared Mac with this same problem and was asked for `sudo` permissions I didn't have.

I tried `echo "" > /var/mail/user` but it didn't fix the problem.

Instead, `cat /dev/null > /var/mail/user` worked perfectly as a substitute to bypass the need for `sudo` permissions.

Edited on Thu, 06 Jul 2023 12:03:17 +0000: The mail path on the Mac was `/var/mail/user`, not `/var/spool/mail/user` as was my original answer.

Comment: That seems odd. Are you sure that `cat /dev/null > /var/spool/mail/user` worked without any additional changes?

Comment: Worked for me verbatim ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯. Edit: Apologies, the mail file location is different, it's `/var/mail/user` so it required a change.

Comment: Your `_echo "" > /var/mail/user_` (, assuming the path is corrected for any given system) would have written a newline to the file, leaving it non-empty and with a modification time ≥ access time. These two criteria trigger the message